# Spring AOP механизм

Tags: spring, java, aop

Добрый день!
Я разбираюсь в AOP, реализованном в Spring. Несколько вещей мне неясны: прежде всего, реализация основана на прокси-объектах. Это означает , что вызовы т.н. JoinPoint методов проксируются.

В основном коде работа ведется не с прокси, а с истинным объектом.Каким образом этот объект "заменяется" прокси? Я так понимаю, что это происходит на уровне байткода?

И еще : кроме прокси, существуют другие методы реализации AOP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring AOP реализует аспекты во время создания бинов. Для каждого бина, для которого создан advice, создаётся proxy-объект при помощи [JDK Dynamyc Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) или [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib). Это объект, наследующийся от исходного или реализующий тот же интерфейс, что и исходный, но вызывающий дополнительные методы до/после/вместо исходных. Именно proxy-объект отдаёт вам Spring вместо исходного бина. Вы этого не замечаете, потому что proxy реализует тот же интерфейс, что и бин (или наследуется от класса бина). Преимуществом такого подхода является то, что он реализуется стандартными средствами JDK, не требующими кастомных класлоадеров или компиляторов. Минусом такого подхода является то, что аспект нельзя применить к static методам и final классам. Это обусловлено тем, что proxy-объекты создаются путём наследования от исходных классов (поэтому нельзя создать proxy к final классу; по этой же причине нельзя применить аспект к static методу: static методы не наследуются) или путём создания класса, реализующего нужный интерфейс (как известно, static методы в интерфейсах не описываются).

Другие подходы реализованы в AspectJ. Там используется свой компилятор, который встраивает аспекты в классы уже на стадии компиляции. Также есть подход с использованием кастомного агента, который контролирует процесс загрузки JVM и встраивает аспекты прямо в байт-код.

Comment: Реализовывать интерфейс он будет в случае если Исходный объект объявлен так : 
     SomeInterface a = new SomeInterfaceImpl();

Наследовать в случае :
     SomeInterfaceImpl a = new SomeInterfaceImpl();

?

Он это определит с помощью рефлексии?

Comment: Во-первых, к объектам, созданным так:

    SomeInterface a = new SomeInterfaceImpl();

аспекты применены не будут, потому что Spring может применить аспекты только к тем объектам, которые сам создаёт (забыл сказать, что, в отличие от того же AspectJ Spring не умеет применять аспекты к конструкторам и свойствам).

Во-вторых, так глубоко во внутренностях Spring'а я не копался, поэтому сказать точно не могу. Вы можете попробовать самостоятельно поотлаживать исходники Spring, благо они в открытом доступе, я сам так в Spring'е прошаривался.